# Sas - how to create a variable having as value the names of flags equal to 1

Tags: sas

I need to do the following stuff with Sas.

I have a dataset like this;

```
ID   flg_1   flg_2   flg_3   ... flg_200
 1     0       1       0     ...   1
 2     1       0       0     ...   0
 3     0       0       1     ...   0
 4     1       1       1     ....  0
 ....
```

I would like to create a new column having the name of flags equal to 1. I mean:

```
ID   flg_1   flg_2   flg_3   ... flg_200   NEW_VAR
 1     0       1       0     ...   1      flg_2-flg_200
 2     1       0       0     ...   0      flg_1 
 3     0       0       1     ...   0      flg_3
 4     1       1       1     ....  0      flg_1-flg_2-flg_3
 ....
```

Could you help me?
thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use a variable based array for iterating over flags and the `vname` to retrieve the variable name.

Example:

```
/* make sure the accumulator variable named 'flagged' is wide
 * enough accommodate the case of all variables being flagged.
 */

data want;
  set have;
  attrib flagged length=$1600 label='List of variables that were flagged';
  array flags flg_1-flg_200;
  do _n_ = 1 to dim(flags);
    if flags(_n_) then flagged = catx(',', flagged, vname(flags(_n_)));
  end;
run;
```